# How to make button disappear on click and show another button?

Tags: css, button, onclick, block

Can some button be block vissible but when you click on button it become none hiden?

Like you have button and click on the button that button disappear and show more 3 button and if you click on any of them it will same disapper and show something else like more buttons?

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('d3').style.display='block'"></button>
```

Comment: Yes, but questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Can you show us what you have tried in a JSFiddle?

Comment: What doesn't work with the `onClick` event you posted? That seems like it would accomplish exactly what you are asking provided the `id` and CSS matchup...

Comment: Hold on! <button onClick="document.getElementById('d3').style.display='block'"></button> is 1990 html4

Answer (score 2):

Considering your explanation didn't give me much to work with, here's a super simple implementation of some of the things I think you're looking for.

**Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/AG3Fz**

CSS

```
<style>
#d3 {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

HTML and JavaScript

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Show more" onclick="showMore()">
<div id="d3">
    <input type="button" value="Show less" onclick="showLess()">
    <input type="button" value="Show less" onclick="showLess()">
    <input type="button" value="Show less" onclick="showLess()">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");

function showMore() {
    button.style.display="none";
    d3.style.display="block";
}

function showLess() {
    button.style.display="inline-block";
    d3.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```